# Rails - Paperclip validating attachment size when it shouldn't be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip

I've got a rails model using Paperclip that looks like this:

```
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :normal => ['857x392#', :png] },
                    :url => '/assets/pages/:id/:basename.:extension',
                    :path => ':rails_root/public/assets/pages/:id/:basename.:extension'

  validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 2.megabytes
```

When attempting to create a record of this model without an attachment to upload, the validation error is returned:

> There were problems with the following
>   fields:
>
> ```
> * Image file size file size must be between 0 and 2097152 bytes.
> ```

I've tried passing both :allow_blank => true and :allow_nil => true after the validation statement in the model, but neither have worked.

How can I allow the :image parameter to be blank?

Answer (score 11):

> validates_attachment_size :image, :in => 0.megabytes..2.megabytes

works now

Answer (score 7):

```
validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 25.megabytes, 
                          :unless => Proc.new {|m| m[:image].nil?}
```

works perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip's validation only checks the range, and doesn't care about the `:allow_nil => true`

What you can do is try to set `:min => nil` or `:min => -1`, maybe that will work.

**Update:**
This will not work in the latest version of Paperclip since they have changed how validations work. 
What you could try instead is:

```
validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 2.megabytes, 
   :unless => Proc.new {|model| model.image }
```

Comment: hmm, which version of paperclip do you use (you can find the version in vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb)?

Comment: I just tried figured this out a few minutes ago. I came back here to report report my results and alas, they are nearly identical to yours. For anyone else with this problem you can also use the hash:

Proc.new { |model| model[:image].nil? }

Comment: Except mine didn't work :) Corrected it now. Good that you solved it.